# Setting true (offset) width/height of a block element with CSS?

Tags: html, block, css

Setting width/height in CSS only corresponds to the content area.  Is there a way to set the offset width/height (i.e. dimensions including padding/margin/borders) of an element in CSS?

**EDIT: Example ->**

I have a number of divs tagged with css class "smallBox"

```
.smallBox{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Now I want to set the padding individually on each box, while having the overall outer dimensions stay the same.

Comment: can you explain it clear , margin borders gets added up after we specify them right , by default they are not added to box model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, sort of. You can change the box model used with the proposed box-sizing CSS3 property, such that the width specifies the total width of the object. Details can be found [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html).

However, browser compatibility is iffy (the article only mentions IE8+ and Firefox), so you will likely need to use JavaScript of some kind to achieve this.

Comment: I hadn't heard of the proposed box-sizing CSS3 property- interesting indeed.  So I guess short answer is no for now, hopefully in future.